# Why is this Point changing?

Tags: java, 2d, point

I am trying to limit the area that a certain cell can go, so I added a `Point spawn` that way I can use`spawn.distance()` to be sure that it doesn't stray too far from its spawn. The problem is that it keeps changing to the cell's current location. As far as I can tell there is nothing that changes it after it is set. Does anyone see a reason it is changing?

Entity Class:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    protected int width, height;

    protected Point location;
    protected CellType cellType;

    abstract void tick();
    abstract void render(Graphics g);

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public CellType getCellType() {
        return cellType;
    }

}
```

Cell Class:

```
public class Cell extends Entity{

    private Random random;

    private CellType cellType;
    private Point spawn;

    private int angle;
    private float xVelocity, yVelocity;
    private float maxVelocity = .2f;

    public Cell(Point location) {
        random = new Random();

        cellType = MasterGame.cellTypes.get(random.nextInt(MasterGame.cellTypes.size()));
        width = MasterGame.cellSizes.get(cellType);
        height = width;
        spawn = location;
        super.location = location;
    }

    int ticks = 0;
    public void tick() {
        if(ticks == 15) {
            System.out.println(spawn);
            angle = random.nextInt(360);
            xVelocity = (float) (maxVelocity * Math.cos(angle));
            yVelocity = (float) (maxVelocity * Math.sin(angle));
            ticks = 0;
        } 
        if(ticks % 3 == 0){
            location.x += xVelocity;
            location.y += yVelocity;
        }
        ticks++;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillOval(location.x, location.y, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval((int)(location.x+(width*.125)), (int)(location.y+(height*.125)), (int)(width*.75), (int)(height*.75));
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The given code doesn´t make it clear what is actually happening at the moment.

Comment: Actually there is code that changes location  `if(ticks % 3 == 0){
            location.x += xVelocity;
            location.y += yVelocity;
        }`

Comment: @MikhailKuchma Not the `location`the `spawn`

Comment: @KevinEsche I do not see anything that is stopping you from replicating this. I gave you the class it extends and the class. It runs just like every other game with `tick()` and `render(Graphics g)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   spawn = location;
   super.location = location;
```

You have two variables that reference *one* object. Use some kind of copy constructor or similar to store original location as `spawn`.